# How to get all error logs from aws cloudwatch using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch, boto, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to get all the error logs from aws cloudwatch, to do this I tried looping through all log group names and running this code:

```
client.start_query(
    logGroupName=group, # log group name
    startTime = int(creation_time)*1000,  # Time the log group was created
    endTime = int(last_event_time.timestamp() * 1000),  # current datetime
    queryString='filter @message like /ERROR/',
)
```

But start_query timeouts after 15 mins, and the only workaround would be limiting time range and this doesn't seem to be a viable option because I wouldn't know what time range would work.
What would be a better approach for this?

Comment: Supplying a restricted time range certainly seems viable. Perhaps you could work out the time range by calling [get_log_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.88/reference/services/logs/client/get_log_events.html) supplying startFromHead=True|False, Once you have the time range you can query some smaller period e.g. weekly or monthly at a time.

Comment: Alternatively, you know the oldest time is when the log group was created and the newest time is now.

Comment: There might be certain days, where logs traffic is more, so cant hard code to go every day.

Comment: There is many log groups which have variable amount of data, and I dont have info how many log files are there in these log groups, so query time is the issue here.